# Configuring log4Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, logging

Im trying to configure the log4cocoa framework to log as DEBUG level messages to the console and INFO level to some file.I cant figure out how it's done.
I have not found any documentation about it, what make things even harder.

This is an example of configuration I`ve tried (not working):

```
log4cocoa.rootLogger=DEBUG,A1

log4cocoa.appender.A1=L4ConsoleAppender
log4cocoa.appender.A1.layout=L4SimpleLayout
log4cocoa.appender.A1.LogToStandardOut=true

log4cocoa.additivity.name=false
log4cocoa.logger.name=INFO,A2

log4cocoa.appender.A2=L4RollingFileAppender
log4cocoa.appender.A2.File=prox.log
log4cocoa.appender.A2.MaximumFileSize=10MB
log4cocoa.appender.A2.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4cocoa.appender.A2.layout=L4PatternLayout
log4cocoa.appender.A2.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p : %m%n
```

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? What happened instead?

Comment: Hi, Peter. I was expecting that my logged data would be appended to the prox.log file and showed on the Console. However, the prox.log is created but no content is appended. :/

Comment: @Leandro Any luck with the proxy.log? I am now stuck at the same position.

Answer (score 1):

In order to write to the file you must add A2 to the rootLogger like this:

log4cocoa.rootLogger=DEBUG,A1,A2